# 503 Service Unavailable after deploy NextJS app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, deployment, next.js, cpanel

so, after trying a few times, it is clear that I am doing something wrong but I do not realize what. My steps are:

1. `rm -rf .next/ && npm run build`
2. upload `.next`, `package.json`,`next.config.js` and `server.js` to cPanel file manager
3. create node JS app from cPanel with `14.18.3` version. (on my local node -v show me `14.18.1`, but on cPanel I don't have this version)
4. run `npm install` with success

then i'm geting 503 service unavailable.

server.js

```
// server.js
const { createServer } = require('http');
const { parse } = require('url');
const next = require('next');

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const hostname = 'localhost';
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
// when using middleware `hostname` and `port` must be provided below
const app = next({ dev, hostname, port });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {
  createServer(async (req, res) => {
    try {
      // Be sure to pass `true` as the second argument to `url.parse`.
      // This tells it to parse the query portion of the URL.
      const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true);
      const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl;

      if (pathname === '/a') {
        await app.render(req, res, '/a', query);
      } else if (pathname === '/b') {
        await app.render(req, res, '/b', query);
      } else {
        await handle(req, res, parsedUrl);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Error occurred handling', req.url, err);
      res.statusCode = 500;
      res.end('internal server error');
    }
  }).listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(`> Ready on http://${hostname}:${port}`);
  });
});
```

package.json scripts

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node server.js",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js"
  },
```

next.config.json

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  basePath: '/apps/nextjs-cpanel',
  trailingSlash: true,
  reactStrictMode: true,
  sassOptions: {
    additionalData: `@import "./styles/variables.scss"; @import "./styles/mixins.scss";`,
  }
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

on cPanel application root is `apps/nextjs-cpanel`, application url is `my-domain/apps/nextjs-cpanel` and application startup file `server.js`

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?
I also have infuriating issue with CPANEL

Comment: Yes, something was wrong with package.json file